# Does having too many View Controllers in a storyboard slow down an IOS app,

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, architecture, uistoryboard

I am currently working on a Spy app with different modules of Spy tools. For my Night Vision module for every mode I use a different View Controller. I also linked all 5 View Controllers together with different Segues, although you can't seem them in this picture.
[image]

I have noticed the performance is not as stellar compared to running an single mode out of a single project. Is it likely the amount of View Controllers slowing the performance down? If so what method do you recommend to cure this problem? The only other difference in the individual project module and the full App project besides the amount of View Controllers/Segues is I use imageViews that work like buttons instead of using buttons.

Comment: 5 view controllers in a storyboard is nothing to worry about. Try to narrow down where the performance lag is, and how bad it is.

Comment: Why do you think you need so many ViewControllers? From what I can see in the screen shot you can accomplish that with one ViewController.  Just change functions on how the ViewController functions based on the option selected. Also is the performance issue in when running the App or in Xcode?

Comment: What part of "Performance" are you talking about? Runtime? Build? Editing?

Comment: Hi , so the camera frame rate is not as fast as it is when it is a single module in  a project. Also every segue transition is laggy and not smooth.  But what I am most concerned with at the moment is the camera lag because it changes the entire feel of the Night Vision. @MikeTaverne and PEEJWEEJ

Comment: @MwcsMac Thank you. The reason I have different View Controllers is the sliders are different to match the different type of processes for the different modes. Also I thought it would be slower to declare so many more variables and more code, so I figured separating the ViewControllers would make the code faster. But if you did something like this in one View Controller would you  make individual class files or just throw all the code in one ViewController file?

Comment: @EricLpFisher With out seeing your code you could use `switch case` to handle the different modes.  Then with classes you could keep the main VC cleaner and then you would also be to reuse the code more cleanly in other parts of the app.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add as many as view controllers in a single storyboard. No performance degrade issue in app but that storyboard will take a time to load in xcode when you open that storyboard.

Comment: This seems to be the universal consensus of the answers I have seen. I probably need to tell the user the app is loading between segues then if I stick with this method.  Thank you for your help.